# Is it possible to use wildcard in Synapse Notebook?

Tags: python, azure-synapse, spark-notebook, azure-notebooks

I want to read parquet files in Synapse Notebook. I tried it using wildcard but the "FileNotFoundError" occurred.
The folder structure I want to read is like this.
`test/year={yyyy}/month={MM}/day={dd}/*.parquet`
And the code executed like this.
`df = pd.read_parquet('abfss://xxx@xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/test/*/*/*/*.parquet', storage_options = '')`

[image]

Any answer would be helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character (*) is not supported in the path of the `pd.read_parquet()` function. It takes `*` as the absolute filepath and tries to read the file. That is the reason for `File not found` error.  To read all the files under specified folder, you can use `spark.read.parquet` function.

**Code:**

```
df = spark.read.parquet('abfss://xxx@xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/test/*/*/*/*')
df.show()
```

[image]